# ActionBarSherlock with Fragments

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm new to Android and using this very useful API. In my application I have a pager and 4 fragments.

I want to update the action bar based on events on each fragment e.g. an OnlistItemClick event. But I can't interfere with the ActionBar from the fragment.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the `ActionBar` from any of your `Fragments` using the `getActivity().getActionBar()` call. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well it's something like that since i use ActionBarSherlock its a bit different.though your answer pointed me to the right direction,I'mjust gonna write what actually worked for me thank you for your time.
        ((SherlockFragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionyBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

Comment: @user1746708, Well, I'm glad you've managed to solved the issue!

Comment: No need to cast. Use `getSherlockActivity()` from within a `SherlockFragment` directly!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ActionBar via `getSupportActionBar()` from your Fragment